# SWT dynamically plotting large amount of data on a limited canvas by increasing its size from bottom and reducing it from top

Tags: swt, eclipse-gef, draw2d

There are lots of  figures I want to plot on a draw2d figurecanvas.figures consume lot of memory. I want them to be plotted serially on the canvas but couldnt because of the memory issue. Now I want to plot them such a way that as when I scroll down, the canvas should be expanded by say x pixels (height)amount at the bottom and new data should be plotted there at the same time some part say x pixels (height) should be removed from the top of the canvas. I tried this by setting the bounds of the canvas but that wouldnt make any difference as the setting the bounds will merely shift the location of the canvas to the new position along with its data

Answer (score 1):

`FigureCanvas` has several methods to scroll programmatically (`scrollTo(..)`, `scrollToX(..)`, etc.). This will change the visible area of your content, which sounds like that you want in the second half of your question. But I don't see how you think this will help with your memory problems. It does not reduce the number of figure objects in your memory.

With Draw2d you describe the whole graphical content (not just the currently visible part) using the figures, and the `FigureCanvas` automatically paints the portion that is currently visible in its viewport. You don't add or remove figures depending on what is currently visible in your canvas.